# How to declare an existing class as an export using MEF?

Tags: c#, .net, singleton, mef

In a project I'm looking through there is a class that looks like this:

```
public static class EventServiceFactory
{
    private static EventAggregator _eventSerice = new EventAggregator();

    public static EventAggregator EventService
    {
        get { return _eventSerice; }
    }
}
```

The first thing I wondered was why a wrapper class was created to make it a singleton but then of course I realized that `EventAggregator` is part of Prism and so obviously can't be modified. This project already uses MEF, and if my understanding is correct MEF uses a shared creation policy by default. So ideally I'm thinking the better option, if possible, would have been to serve up the `EventAggregator` class using MEF. But is that possible? How would I do this when I can't add attributes to the EventAggregator class, or is there a way?